# Windowsでコマンドのエイリアスを作りたい

Tags: windows, command-line

Linuxで

```
alias bs="browser-sync start --server --files *.html,*.css,*.js"
```

として `bs` をショートカットコマンドとして使っていましたが、Windowsのコマンドラインで同じようにするにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

doskeyコマンドじゃダメですか？

```
doskey bs=browser-sync start --server --files *.html,*.css,*.js
```

って感じで行けると思います。

あとは、pathの通ったところにbatファイル作って、batの中に処理を書くとか。

---

ただ、doskeyだとコマンドプロンプトを開く度に設定してやらんといかんので、コマンドプロンプトのショートカットに起動オプション`/k doskey /macrofie=c:\wk\alias.txt`とかって付けてあげて、alias.txtに設定したいaliasを羅列しといてやる必要があります。
当然、ショートカットにオプションを指定していないとaliasが有効になりません。
なので、個人的にはpath通ったところにbatファイル色々作って置くという方法を選んでいます。